# Не удается добиться оптимальной анимации

Tags: css, html5, css-animation

```
.sst {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap:15px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s all ease-in-out;
}

.open .sst {
  animation: opp .3s ease-in-out 1 normal forwards
}

@keyframes opp {
  0% {padding-top:0; height: 0; opacity: 0}
  to {padding-top:15px; height: unset; opacity: 1}
}
```

При наличии класса open, открываем блок, увеличиваем высоту по дочерним блокам, увеличиваем padding и opacity;

Добавляем класс open, анимация работает. Но как выполнить так, чтобы анимация была противоположной, удалив класс open и не добавляя новых?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  animation.style.display = 'flex';
  animation.classList.add('open');
});
trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => animation.classList.remove('open'));
```

```css
#trigger {
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.sst {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 3s all ease-in-out;
  background: rosybrown;
  animation: opp_up .3s ease-in-out normal forwards;
}

.sst.open {
  animation: opp_down .3s ease-in-out normal forwards;
}

@keyframes opp_down {
  from {
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: unset;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes opp_up {
  to {
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  from {
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: unset;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="trigger">Hover me</div>
<div id="animation" class="sst"></div>
```

Comment: Отлично, пытаюсь выполнить без присвоения display через js, вроде работает. Но, к примеру если через js добавить html блок какой нибудь В РОДИТЕЛЯ(не в тот на котором анимация), то анимация вновь повторяется. Возможно ли и добавить блок так, чтобы анимация не повторилась, и не прибегая к присвоению свойства display через JS

Comment: Возможно ли animation-direction: reverse, применить, дабы дважды не прописывать?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, фишка в том, что в css надо `display: none`, а через js уже указывать `display` какой надо, тогда не будет лишних анимаций при открытии страницы или добавлении блока. И к сожалению этот способ не работает с animation-direction: reverse

Comment: Хорошо, вот присвоили flex, анимация вроде как работает. Но, если присвоить none в момент когда необходимо обратная анимация. Блок просто пропадает.  Если ее не присваивать и добавить в родительский блок html, анимация будет повторяться...

Comment: Не надо присваивать `none` и повторений не будет. В моем коде нет присваивания `none`